# Google Chrome for Windows 10. How to open all the profiles at once?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

The google startup icon typically located at "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application" will open the last open profile(s) by default. Is there a way to make it so that it opens all profiles at once all the time, regardless of wether 1 or 5 profiles were opened at shut down?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use batch file to launch all your profiles at once

Something like this -

```
start "Chrome" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory="Profile 2"


start "Chrome" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory="Profile 3"
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll that.

Comment: @Philippe feel free to accept the answer is it helped!!

Comment: Something that worked for me on MacOS: If you de-select "Show on startup" then Quit Chrome with all your desired profiles open, next time you open Chrome, it opens all those profiles again. In Windows, try de-selecting "Show on startup", then using "Exit Google Chrome" from the 3-vertical-dots menu (while all your profiles are open). Then launch Chrome as normal (without mentioning any profile). It should open all profiles again. Note: This may require "On startup: Continue where you left off" and YMMV. Note also that if you pin to Windows taskbar it may be locked to a specific profile.